# How to insert an image in Word with an userform in Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, userform

I have created an userform in Excel which has an image picker that saves the chosen file as the image of a picture. ( Image1.Picture) 
I need to make a button that copies that image and appends it to an existing Word Document but I can't manage to make it work. Any idea? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow: you wrote you can t manage to make it work, can you show us what you tried so far and where you got stucked? People will be gladly helping here to make your code work

Answer (score 0):

Try this function, I have built the function that inserts the image at `strImagePath` to the document at `strDocPath` (e.g "D:\MyImage.img" and "D:\MyDoc.docx").
If you have a problem with image types (.jpg or .gif,etc), do a research with function `objShapes.AddPicture`

```
Function FnImageInsert(strImagePath, strDocPath)
  Dim objWord
  Dim objDoc
  Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strDocPath)
  objWord.Visible = True      
  objWord.Selection.TypeText (vbCrLf & "One Picture will be inserted here....")
  objDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture (strImagePath)
End Function
```

Then you can create a userform to insert these paths and run the function.
Hope it is helpful.